# newbie python modulo unexpected result

Tags: python, modulo

Could use some help as I don't really see where I'm going wrong:

`totalseconds/86400`

`1.2494560185185186`

`totalseconds%86400`

`21553`

Shouldnt I be getting `24945`...?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is `totalseconds`?

Comment: totalseconds=107953

Comment: `21553` + `86400` = `107953`, so the modulo is correct.

Comment: Why do you think you should get `24945...` ??? @UTSloth

Comment: Ok... so I guess I was wrong about what the % does?? I thought it returned your decimal...?

Comment: ...I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

modulo is the remainder after division, not the fractional part of the decimal.